# How to make Gnome Shell extension query for changes

Tags: javascript, gnome-3, gnome-shell-extensions

I've been battling the horrendous Gnome API documentation and came up with this extension:

```
const St = imports.gi.St;
const Main = imports.ui.main;
const Tweener = imports.ui.tweener;
const GLib = imports.gi.GLib;

let label;

function init() {
    label = new St.Bin({ style_class: 'panel-label' });

    let stuff = GLib.spawn_command_line_sync("cat /home/user/temp/hello")[1].toString();
    let text = new St.Label({ text: stuff });

    label.set_child(text);
}

function enable() {
    Main.panel._rightBox.insert_child_at_index(label, 0);
}

function disable() {
    Main.panel._rightBox.remove_child(label);
}
```

This should read whatever is in the `hello` file and display it in the top panel. However, if I change the contents of the `hello` file, I have to restart Gnome for that new content to be shown. Now, surely there is a way to do this dynamically but I just couldn't find anything in the documentation. The message in the panel should basically always mirror whatever is in the file. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to obtain a `Gio.File` handle for your `hello` file, and then [monitor](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-monitor) it:

```
let helloFile = Gio.File.new_for_path('/home/user/temp/hello');
let monitor = helloFile.monitor(Gio.FileMonitorFlags.NONE, null);
monitor.connect('changed', function (file, otherFile, eventType) {
    // change your UI here
});
```

Comment: This is great! I wish this stuff was clearly documented somewhere :( One more question: how would you monitor the output of a command? Let's say I want to run ping and display the time of each packet in the top panel? Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's worth an entire question-and-answer on its own, but this C code might get you started: https://github.com/ptomato/gnome-inform7/blob/master/src/spawn.c#L215 Speaking of C code, unfortunately your best alternative to proper GJS documentation is to read the C API: https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFileMonitor.html#GFileMonitor-changed

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. It will refresh the label value each 30 seconds.

- Add the following import

  const Mainloop = imports.mainloop;
- In your init method

  ```
  Mainloop.timeout_add(30000, function () { 
   let stuff = GLib.spawn_command_line_sync("your_command")[1].toString();
   let label = new St.Label({ text: stuff });
   button.set_child(label);return true});
  ```